# vb.net program that generates code and copy it to clipboard

Tags: vb.net

I'm planning to create a vb.net program that generates mysql codes.
Is is possible that after the program has generated the code, it will copy it in to the clipboard immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clipboard.SetText("some test")
```

If this program is command line, you'll need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can just use the Clipboard.SetText(text As String) method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the same code;

```
Clipboard.SetText(Password)
```